# How to Analyze and Query big chunks of data

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, mapreduce, google-bigquery

I need to:

### 1. Analyze big files of http logs

- I'm thinking in using mapreduce but I'm not sure where to host it. Shall I use App Engine Mapper or EC2+MapReduce or simply use it in my VPS?
- Other suggestions besides MapReduce?

### 2.Save and query the results

- After analyzing all the data I need to save it and present to the user in the best possible way. How should I save the results? Is MongoDB a good solution for this?

Thanks.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen [BigQuery](http://code.google.com/apis/bigquery/)? It looks like exactly what you need.